# Visual Studio 2017 Application Manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am currently trying to create an Application Manifest for my C# (Universal Windows) project in visual studio 2017. I created the App Manifest and named it App2.manifest. App2 is the name of the project. I have read in other posts that you have to go in properties and tell the project which manifest to use, but I am unable to find the option they are talking about and think that it only applied to older versions of VS.

I am certain that my manifest is not working because when I add the following line to it, It does not prompt me to give admin access

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is not sensible.  A UWP already has a manifest, the AppX manifest that is required to ask for capabilities and list the package content.  You are talking about the kind of manifest that a desktop program requires.   That cannot work.  Nor can a UWP app ever gain admin privileges, it runs in a sandbox that prevents doing anything unwise with a UAC level that is below "normal".  If you need this then you need to stop using a UWP project template.

Comment: So if I wanted to make a desktop application that can be run as an administrator what would I choose? Sorry for the beginner questions

Comment: Pick something from the "Windows Classic Desktop" subset.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong kind of application which was my problem.